# Attempt to de-reference a null object Error when getting map value

Tags: apex

I am getting an Attempt to de-reference a null object error when attempting to get the status value from the m_cl map.  In my debug I can see there are values in the map.

```
Map<String, Checklist__c> m_cl = new Map<String, Checklist__c>();
Map<Id,Checklist__c> m_cl = new Map<Id, Checklist__c>();
Set<Id> checkListIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> prjIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> prjNcIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> checkListNcIds = new Set<Id>();
string status;

    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {            
        for (SObject so : Trigger.New) {
          Checklist__c newCL = (Checklist__c) so;
          Checklist__c oldCL = Trigger.oldMap != null && Trigger.oldMap.containsKey(newCL.Id)
            ? (Checklist__c) Trigger.oldMap.get(newCL.Id)
            : null;

                if(newCL.Status__c != oldCL.Status__c && (newCL.Status__c == 'Complete' || oldCL.Status__c == 'In Progress')){
                    m_cl.put(newCL.Id, newCL);;
                    checkListIds.add(newCL.Id);
                    prjIds.add(newCL.Project__c);
                }

        }

    for(Id clId : m_cl.keySet())
       {
           Object clObject = m_cl.get(clId);
           String clStatus = clObject.Status__c; //does not exist
       }


        if(checkListIds.size()> 0){
            act = [Select id,Name,Project__c, Project__r.RC_Completed__c, Project__r.M5_Completed__c,Checklist__r.Status__c,Checklist__r.Name,Checklist__c,Form_Complete__c
                  FROM Activity__c 
                  WHERE Form_Complete__c = false 
                  AND Checklist__c IN : checkListIds
                  ];

            prj = [Select id, Name, RC_Completed__c ,M5_Completed__c 
                   FROM Project__c 
                   WHERE Id IN : prjIds];
          
      system.debug('m_cl ' +m_cl);
            if(m_cl != null){
                status = m_cl.get('Id').Status__c;  //getting error here
                 system.debug('status value ' +status);
            }


            if( act.size() > 0){
                for(Activity__c acts : act){
                    formName = acts.Checklist__r.Name.split(':');    
                    if(formName[1] == 'Pre-M5 Check List Form' {
                        acts.M5_Completed__c = true;
                        actToUpdate.add(acts);
                    }
                    else {
                        acts.RC_Completed__c = true;
                        actToUpdate.add(acts);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried searching SFSE for `NullPointerException`? This is a very common issue; it looks like `m_cl` does not contain a key for the value `Id`.

Comment: Hey @DavidReed, I have looked at a few.  I originally had the map as <Id, Checklist__c> but then received ' Invalid id: Id' error.  That is why I switched it to <String,Checklist__c>.  I can see the id of the record, just not referencing correctly.  I will look some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be populating and accessing your Map using two different kinds of values:

```
m_cl.put(newCL.Activity__c, newCL);
```

We don't know the value type of `Activity__c`, but presumably it is either an `Id` or `String`.

You then attempt to access your Map using the *literal string `Id`* as the key:

```
status = m_cl.get('Id').Status__c;  //getting error here
```

If `Activity__c` is in fact an Id, you need to locate the appropriate Id value and use it as the expected Map key. In the context of this code, it's not at all clear what that value is.

Comment: Apologies.  This was a typo.  should read:   m_cl.put(newCL.Id, newCL);

Comment: OK - answer stands, though. The literal string `'Id'` is not an Id value

Comment: Ok. Tried a different approach(updated code above) but Status field is still saying not available. Am I going down the right path to get the Status field?  Thanks